# Unitary matrix with all its eigenvalues equal to 1 must be the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Let $A$ be a unitary matrix over field $F$ ($F=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$)
Prove that if all its eigenvalues equal to $1$ then $A$ must be the identity matrix $I$.

I am having a hard time figuring out where to begin. Thanks.

Comment: What do you know about (the structure of) unitary matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the matrix is unitary, then it is diagonalisable, and if all eigenvalues are one, then there exists a matrix $V$ such that:

$$A=VIV^{-1}=VV^{-1}=I$$

Being $A$ our matrix.

EDIT:

As I saw in the comments, your actual question is how do we know that unitary matrices are diagonalizable. Here you have the proof:

http://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/m640_03c/lectures/chapter4.pdf

Page 5 (161)

Comment: But how do you know that if the matrix A has the Eigenvalue 1 repeated n times it will be digonalizable ?                    That is how do you know that the matrix has n distinct Eigenvectors ?  And after that we can conclude that there exist matrix V that will diagonalize A

Comment: Or how do we know that the Algebraic Multiplicity of 1 will be equal to the Geometric Multiplicity of its corresponding Eigenspace ?

Comment: If F=C then because A is in particular Normal then Q is Unitarily Diagonalizable which implies that A is Diagonalizable which implies that there exist an invertible matrix P such that inv(P)*A*P = I and we can conclude that A = I,                                                           But if F=R then I get stuck and can't go on ?                In other words how do we know that the Orthogonal matrix A is digonalizable over R ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the result remains true when you replace "unitary" by "diagonalisable".

Comment: But how do we know that unitary matrix is diagonalizable ?